# jQuery multiple .not() selector based on parent element

Tags: jquery

So let's say I have 4 sections, within each section I have an element I want to modify but not for the elements within the first and last sections. How would I write the `.not()` selector? Here's what I've tried:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.header', 'section').not('#one, #four').height('200');
});
```

```css
.header {
  background:black;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="one">
  <div class="header"></div>
</section>

<section id="two">
  <div class="header"></div>
</section>

<section id="three">
  <div class="header"></div>
</section>

<section id="four">
  <div class="header"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir that won't help as the restriction is being placed on the wrong element. Having multiple selectors in a single `not()` call is valid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to put the `:not` restriction on the `section` elements. You're currently applying it to the `.header` instead. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.header', 'section:not(#one, #four)').height(200);
});
```

```css
.header {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="one">
  <div class="header">one</div>
</section>

<section id="two">
  <div class="header">two</div>
</section>

<section id="three">
  <div class="header">three</div>
</section>

<section id="four">
  <div class="header">four</div>
</section>
```